# Prevent TinyMCE's dialogs to escape browser view

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Looks like it is possible to drag the TinyMCE dialogs (e.g. "source code" or "insert link") outside of the browser space, especially when using two screens. This is reproducible with the TinyMCE demo on https://www.tinymce.com/. If the user drags the dialogues out of his browser view, it may be hard to even close them when the users clicks elsewhere, the dialog loses it's focus and <kbd>ESC</kbd> doesn't work anymore (randomly pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>and <kbd>Enter</kbd>helps).

[image: Tiny MCE dialog trying to escape]
Is there any way to prohibit the user moving the dialogues out of the viewport?